# Neovim/Vim: Resize window based on type of buffer

Tags: vim, neovim

Using Neovim's terminal emulator to run code alongside my code has become an essential part of my workflow ever since I found out about it. I however would like to have a way to make it so that when I open a new nvim terminal window it will be narrow opposed to currently when I open one and it takes up half the screen.

I don't fully understand vimscript which is part of the issue here. I have looked into how to make an autocommand run based on a filetype and how to resize windows and cobbled together something based on these. It doesn't work as it resizes the whole vim session instead of just the desired window.

```
au BufWinEnter * if &buftype == 'terminal' | resize 20 | endif
```

I have looked into golden-ratio for a plugin but I don't want the terminal window getting bigger when I move around; I just want it to be small and off to the side.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with `terminal` is that `buftype` is set **after** `BufWinEnter`. So you must catch `TerminalOpen` (in Vim) or `TermOpen` (in Neovim) instead.

```
augroup myterm | au!
    au TermOpen * if &buftype ==# 'terminal' | resize 20 | vert resize 50 | endif
augroup end
```

Also note:

1. Always make use of `augroup` to be able to clear or redefine your autocommands.
2. Always use `==#` or `==?` when comparing strings, so you'll never depend on the `ignorecase` option setting.
3. You still have to check `&buftype`, because the terminal can start hidden (i.e. w/o any window attached). In this case the terminal's buffer will be available in `<abuf>`, but `%` will point to the active/visible buffer.

Comment: Great answer! Only nit is that using `| au!` makes that too invisible. At a glance, I first thought it was missing. Having `au!` on its own line at the top of the augroup would have been better IMO, also more idiomatic (based on examples on help files, guides and tutorials, vimrc and plug-in distros, etc.)

Comment: @filbranden Well, I like it this way :) It looks to me as if I'm starting "a clean autogroup" with "a single command". But that's very subjective, of course.

Comment: I like it this way to, for the same reason. Updating my own vimrc to resemble that, haha!

Comment: I really like this solution but the resize doesn't seem to effect the width of the window it seems to only effect the height of the vim session which is strange. Does the fact that I am opening the window with ":vsplit term://zsh" possibly affect anything?

Comment: @HANSLARSSON For vertical resize you use `vert resize X`.
`":vsplit term://zsh" possibly affect anything?` Actually, you **must** have an adjacent vertical split for vertical resize to work, otherwise your single window will occupy as much width as possible. On the other hand, the horizontal resize always works, because there's at least a command window in the bottom of a tabpage.

Comment: Thank you so much that fixed it right on up and thank you for being so clear and concise with your answers!

Comment: For neovim this works: `autocmd BufWinEnter,WinEnter term://* startinsert | resize 16 | vert resize 50`

Comment: @rofrol `BufWinEnter term://*` can't match in Neovim, unless you invoke terminal as `:e term://sh` or alike. And `WinEnter term://*` is not guranteed to trigger. Consider `:new`, and after that (so the newly created window was already made active) `:term`. You won't get any more `WinEnter` until you manually switch windows back and forth.

Comment: @Matt in neovim I get: `No such group or event: TerminalOpen`

Comment: @rofrol In Neovim it's called `TermOpen`

Answer (score 1):

Refering to the [help](https://vimhelp.org/terminal.txt.html#terminal-resizing), you only need to set the ['termwinsize'](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27termwinsize%27) option.

For example :

```
set termwinsize=0x50
```

Will make `vertical terminal` open a terminal vertical split, 50 columns wide.

```
set termwinsize=20x0
```

Lets `terminal` open a terminal horizontal split, 20 lines tall.

Comment: `termwinsize` sets the terminal's size, but it does **not** adjust the Vim's window size.

Comment: Indeed, but I think that's what the OP wants ("I just want it to be small and off to the side."). With only `tws`, you can `vert terminal` the size you want. I edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: I have tried your option and I continually get the error E518: Unknown option: termwinsize=20x0 although this does sound like it should work. I also don't know if it is that I am opening the window with the command ":vsplit term://zsh"

Comment: That's another question indeed. If it works with the regular `terminal` command, and not for `term://zsh`, I suggest you'd open another topic.